# Reducing signal voltage with pull-down resistor

Tags: resistors, voltage-divider, gpio

I have a signal that is really high compared to the inputs of a microcontroller and i have to step it down a bit....

Can I use a pull down resistor between the signal and the GND? Will this step down the voltage of the signal so it is acceptable?

Or will the signal go to GND indiscriminately?

I have to step down the voltage of a sensor, in order to be read by an Arduino that accepts 5V input max.

This is the sensor in question:
Inductive Proximity Sensor 18mm - LJ18A3-8-Z/AX

This is its datasheet:
https://cdn.awsli.com.br/945/945993/arquivos/14_PROXIMITY_INDUCTIVE_18BY.pdf

This is the circuit described:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiPhOW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There's too little detail to answer from. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Explain your situation, details the parts involved and show a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Incidentally, what you describe as voltage regulation is actually signal conditioning - regulation would apply to supplied power rails.

Comment: Not a single resistor but two that form a potential divider.

Comment: A mere pulldown resistor won't do the job. If you only want to use passive components, you need a voltage divider (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

Comment: Ok. One sensor produces 24 V output. A friend of mine claims to be able to read that sensor with an arduino, by connectiong the signal with a resistance that goes to ground. The signal is fed to to arduino. I thought that this connnection would drop the signal voltage to zero.... This is why i am asking for confirmation.

Comment: Please look at this schematic. This is what he referneced: https://electropeak.com/learn/interfacing-inductive-proximity-sensor-lj12a3-4-z-3-wire-with-arduino/

Comment: @user1584421 The link you posted shows a voltage divider (formed by two 10k resistors) to reduce the output from 9V do 4.5V.

Comment: Please edit new information into your question, don't post it in comments. Otherwise readers have to piece the full question together. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question with a poorly drawn schematic. Could you please take a look at it and tell me if this would work?

Comment: I updated the question with the sensor name. Sorry for the ommision.

Comment: @Seir Realy appreciate the edit. Thank you.

Comment: Link the sensor's datasheet in the question. It may or may not be possible and the datasheet should answer that. But a voltage divider is a safer bet.

Comment: @user_1818839 I updated the question with the datasheet of the sensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a detailed datasheet for your LJ18A3-8-Z/AX Sensor, only a variety of technical summaries on sales websites. I haven't linked to any of those as such a link would be too fragile.

What the few I looked at had in common was the sensor having an 'NPN NC' output. So that suggests an NPN transistor operating like a Normally Closed switch, giving approx. 0.3 V to GND in one switching state and open-collector or a pulled-high voltage in the other.

An interface circuit for this is shown below and uses one diode and one resistor.

When the sensor NPN_NC output is high, NPN_NC either (a) pulls D1's cathode up to the sensor's 24 V rail and reverse-biases it, or (b) leaves D1's cathode high-impedance and D1 not conducting. D1 is a BAT54, so the 19 V across it is well below its 30 V maximum. GPIO(in) is pulled logic HIGH by R1.

When the sensor NPN_NC output is low, D1 conducts and clamps R1 and GPIO(in) down at approx. (VNPN_NC(low) + 0.2 V) or 0.5 V. GPIO(in) is a good logic LOW.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Kir3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: +1 for the effort in overcoming the terrible documentation available (even a manufacturer site does not inform internal connections or at least both the current source and sink capabilities) and the creative solution in this scenario.

Comment: You can (almost certainly) omit the diode though it's a safety feature. Now that the OP added the datasheet to the question it's clearly an open collector NPN which will pull down, but never pull its output up to its own supply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I have to ask you something specific though. 1. Is the pull-down technique that he uses valid? I dont think it is. 2. If it's not valid, then how come it works (most of the time). 3. When it does not work, the sensor is ruined. Can you figure out why the sensor is destroyed?

Comment: @user1584421, if it works sometimes the part you have must have a pull-up, so the 2K pull-down would work, but may not. The datasheet is too ambiguous, we're having to guess-conclude from it when it should be definitive. So I can't make all the deductions that your comment wants or do analysis on situations full of unknowns. Using this circuit, it doesn't matter because it's cheap and it'll work, whether internal pull-up or none. The answer explains that and you're very welcome to the help. I've used this circuit in mass-production for this stuff with great success.

Comment: But the fact that sometimes the sensor may get destroyed, does that make sense to you? Also, is the circuit you provided safe to use for the arduino? Keep in mind, the signal is 24V. Will this circuit drop the value of the signal to 5v?

Comment: @user1584421, yes it is safe and suitable, as said before and as the answer states. This is getting exhausting. Please read the actual answer rather than asking further questions already answered in it. Bear in mind that it's a Q&A site, not a forum for discussions like this in comments, such as trying to fault-find existing sensors. Why not build this circuit and try it instead.

Answer (score 3):

ElectroPeak already provided the answer:

> **Warning**
>
> *Since the output voltage is more than 5 volts, we use voltage divider to connect the sensor output to Arduino.*

<sub>Quote source: [Electropeak - *Interfacing Inductive Proximity Sensor LJ12A3-4-Z/BY with Arduino* by Amir Mohammad Shojaei](https://electropeak.com/learn/interfacing-inductive-proximity-sensor-lj12a3-4-z-3-wire-with-arduino/)</sub>

Following voltage divider would do the job:

24V * 2.4k / (9.1k + 2.4k) = 5V

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foADAg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Here](https://botland.store/inductive-contactless-sensors/11872-inductive-proximity-sensor-lj12a3-4-z-by-4mm-6-36v.html) I found *some* info:

> **Connection**
>
> - Brown wire - supply voltage
> - Blue wire - ground - GND
> - Black wire - digital output - OUT
>
>   - there is no object - low status
>   - object detection - high status

Without more detailed specifications, we have to assume that the output is low-impedance. So you have to properly protect the 5V input.

Comment: Thank you... But a friend claims that the circuit works with only a pull down resistor.. I have seen the circuit work myself (not too sure of the connections though). Although his circuit breaks down sometimes and he doesn't know why. But since sometimes it works, he claims that you CAN use a pull down resistor to step down the voltage. My question is, is this possible?

Comment: No, a single pulldown resistor wouldn't reduce the voltage applied to the microcontroller. If the sensor is powered by 6V, it's possible that a 5V controller won't fry immediately (you'd have the check the electrical specs).

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with a poorly drawn schematic of what i describe. Could you please take a loot at it?

Comment: @user1584421 Your friend is wrong.

Comment: Maybe the sensor has a high output resistance so that a single resistor to ground could work, not enough information about the sensor to say.

Comment: I updated the question with the sensor name. Sorry for the ommision.

Comment: @Unimportant I knew that this topology does not work in general. Why does it work for him (not all the times). Am i missing something?

Comment: @user1584421 We are all missing something: proper technical documentation about the sensor. Note that the diagram you provide, with an implicit high output resistance from the sensor, would form a voltage divider.

Comment: @devnull Here is the datasheet for the specific sensor: https://cdn.awsli.com.br/945/945993/arquivos/14_PROXIMITY_INDUCTIVE_18BY.pdf

Comment: @user1584421: the datasheet says the output current of the sensor is 200 mA, so your 2K resistor won't work to pull the output down to a safe voltage for the Arduino - you would need a voltage divider.

Comment: The fact that "his circuit breaks down sometimes and he doesn't know why" is a very strong indicator that he is wrong wouldn't you think?

Comment: @PeterBennett Thank you. Could you explain how you figured this out, to me?

Comment: @user1584421: The datasheet says the sensor output can deliver 200 mA.  Your 2K resistor will only draw 12 mA, so it won't affect the output voltage very much.